# Multiple static const int class variables in DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, static

I'm working on a legacy VS2015 app that creates several DLLs.  They all include a certain .h file that declares/defines static data.  After preprocessing that becomes:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) J
{
public:
   static const unsigned int SA_UNSPECIFIED  = 1;
   ...
};
```

In my app `.cpp` file I include the same .h file, and that preprocesses (`#ifdef`, etc.) to this:

```
class __declspec(dllimport) J
{
public:
   static const unsigned int SA_UNSPECIFIED  = 1;
   ...
};
```

My main symptom is that my app says that during link it cannot find `J::SA_UNSPECIFIED`.  The app "References" (using the "Reference" tree in VS) these other DLLs that export `J`.

I think this is different from ["Why static variable needs to be explicitly defined?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223949/why-static-variable-needs-to-be-explicitly-defined) in that I'm using const integral, as opposed to the general case.  Is this not true in this case?

1. Am I even allowed to do this?  That is, have `static const` data defined in several different dlls, and expect it to work?
2. I tried taking out the assignments, and putting them into a separate .cpp file.  But some of the code uses the `static const` vars in `case` statements.  That works fine until I take out the assignment; then `case` says it needs a constant expression (of course).
3. I can't `inline` these; VS says that's an error.
4. Other developers in the group, using identical code and project files, can build without error.  I haven't yet compared VS versions.

**Answer:**
It turns out that in my app I use `SA_UNSPECIFIED` in a non-integral way, and so can no longer be initialized in the class definition.

Comment: Did you actually define the member in an implementation file?  `const U32 J::SA_UNSPECIFIED;`

Comment: No. I assumed (uh-oh!) that as it was `static const int` I didn't need to. I did try to do that (define in an implementation file and take out of the `.h'), but then the variables can no longer be used in a `case`.

Comment: You can leave the `= 1` in the header file so that the value can still be used, but you still need the definition (with no initializer) in the source file.