# ODR bug in MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-bug, one-definition-rule

This program prints `1 1` instead of `1 2` when compiled with MSVC (up to VS 2015).

*f1.cpp:*

```
#include <functional>

static std::function<int ()> helper() {
    struct F { int operator()() { return 1; } };
    return F();
}

std::function<int ()> f1() { return helper(); }
```

*f2.cpp:*

```
#include <functional>

static std::function<int ()> helper() {
    struct F { int operator()() { return 2; } };
    return F();
}

std::function<int ()> f2() { return helper(); }
```

*main.cpp:*

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

std::function<int ()> f1();
std::function<int ()> f2();

int main() {
    std::cout << f1()() << " " << f2()() << "\n";
}
```

It's as if the different definitions of `F` are breaking ODR. But shouldn't local classes be distinct? Interestingly, if we replace `F` with lambda functions there is no conflict.

So is this a compiler bug or am I misunderstanding the one definition rule?

Comment: Bit crazy that MSVC gets something like this wrong. It even gets it wrong if you remove the `static` and use an unnamed namespace.

Comment: What happens when you use two separate couts instead of one?

Comment: Are you sure? With MSVC 14.0, if `helper()` is put in anonymous namespace then the conflict goes away.

Comment: No point is separating couts.

Comment: Huh. I'm getting `1 2` now. I swear I was getting `1 1` when I wrote that comment. :P

Comment: Nevermind it was my build environment. It wasn't detecting that `f1.cpp` and `f2.cpp` had changed.

Comment: I wonder if this is due to aggressive [COMDAT folding](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26533740/1708801) you can turn it off by using [/opt:noicf](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29057190/1708801)

Comment: Let me know if using `/opt:noicf ` fixes it or not, it seems like a stretch but I have seen some interesting breaks due to this so it is worth a try.

Comment: Getting the same behavior with `/link /opt:noicf`. I assume folding applies only to functions with identical definitions, which is not the case here.

Comment: If you are using C++ >= 11, you could try moving `F` out of the function and into an anonymous namespace in your source files.

Comment: I  dont think it  is  a odr issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearly a bug in MSVC, as all the types are unique. Perhaps for structs defined inside some function (in this case `helper`) MSVC internally treats them as if they are defined as `helper::F` while if helper is static it should have done something like this `f1_cpp::helper::F` instead.
As a result at link time linker sees two identically named inline functions and merges them into one.

Most likely by reordering input files you can get `2 2` if you weren't happy with `1 1` :)