# Is function pointer comparison in a constexpr function allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer, constexpr

Suppose I have a constexpr array of function pointers, and I want to write a constexpr function to find the array index for a specified function.

I might have code like this:

```
void test1(){}void test2(){}void test3(){}void test4(){}

typedef void(*func)(void);
constexpr func funcs[] = { &test1, &test2, &test3 };

constexpr int FindMatchingIdx (const func work, const int idx) {
    return (work == funcs[idx]) ? (idx) : (FindMatchingIdx(work, idx + 1));
}

constexpr unsigned int loc = FindMatchingIdx (&test1,0);
```

Now this code compiles on Clang and MSVC, however GCC will only compile when `FindMatchingIdx` is called with the first element in the array. If `FindMatchingIdx` is called with `test1`, GCC will compile the code, however if `FindMatchingIdx` is called with `test2` or `test3` GCC will fail to compile the code, giving the error message:

> error: '(test1 != test2)' is not a constant expression.

If `FindMatchingIdx` has to recurse, GCC will fail to treat it as a constexpr function. Is this a bug in GCC? How does function pointer comparison even work inside a constexpr function? Obviously it can't be using real pointer values as those are assigned by the linker.

Working example: https://godbolt.org/g/xfv1PM

Comment: It looks like a bug to me, that is probably `operator!=(T, T)` where `T` is a function pointer is not `constexpr` while `operator==(T, T)` it is.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this is *why* gcc is complaining, but there is [*some* arguable ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26533740/1774667) in the standard about if `test1` and `test2` have distinct addresses, and hence compare equal.

If the standard is actually ambiguous there, then gcc is right in saying `test1 != test2` is unspecified by the standard.  Meanwhile, `test1==test1` is specified by the standard.

The inequality of function pointers being like that has the benefit that it permits the compiler to assign two distinct functions with identical binary implementations the same address.  So `test1` and `test2` and `test3` would be distinct functions with the same address, and pointers to them would compare equal.