# Why can't I use std::function as a std::set or std::unordered_set value type?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, std-function, stdset

Why can't I have a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` of `std::function`s?

Is there any way to get it to work anyway?

Comment: What do you mean with doesn't work?

Comment: Because you can't apply `std::less` (needed by `std::set`) nor `std::hash` and `std::equal_to` (needed by `std::unordered_set`) to it.

Comment: There is no meaningfull way to implement those for `std::function`, but with type erasure you should be able to write a wrapper around `std::function`, supporting hashing & comparsion, provided that the functors you initialize your `std::function`s with support those. (If nobody does before, I'll post an answer in a few hours.)

Comment: @JVApen Thought it was pretty clear from the title; they're not allowed to be used as value types with sets.

Comment: @Qix: compile errors would really be useful!

Comment: @Qix Take the case for `std::set`.  What makes one function "less than" another?  What would be the criteria?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat couldn't the implementation hash the lambda captures (if any) against the entry point address to determine equality, in theory?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie True; I suppose a decision could be made to base it on the address but there are a number of caveats with that.

Comment: @Qix It should be possible, but somebody would have to write a standard proposal for that. :) Currently, you can make a wrapper for `std::function` that can forward hashing/comparsion to stored functors, but you can't hash/compare stateful lambdas.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using a set? If your `std::function` has state, then you might never get the same key/hash value thus making a set useless. Why not use a vector? If you want to identifying functions, then a map with incremental ID as the key might be more appropriate. You would keep the id as a reference to the actual function.

Comment: Yeah @Phil1970 that's what I'm doing after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't I have a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` of `std::function`s?

`std::set` relies on a comparator, which is used to determine if one element is less than the other.

It uses `std::less` by default, and `std::less` doesn't work with `std::function`s.
(Because there is no way to properly compare `std::function`s.)

Similarly, `std::unordered_set` relies on `std::hash` and `std::equal_to` (or custom replacements for them), which also don't operate on `std::function`s.

---

> Is there any way to get it to work anyway?

You can write a wrapper around (or a replacement for) `std::function` that works with `std::less`, `std::equal_to` and/or `std::hash`.

Via power of *type erasure*, you can forward `std::less`/`std::equal_to`/`std::hash` to  objects stored in your wrapper.

Here's a proof-of-concept for such a wrapper.

Notes:

- You can specify whether or not you want the `class FancyFunction` to work with `std::less`, `std::equal_to` and `std::hash` separetely, by adjusting a template argument.
  If some of those is enabled, you'll be able to apply them to `FancyFunction`.

  Naturally, you'll be able to construct `FancyFunction` from a type only if they can be applied to that type.

  There is a static assertion that fires when a type fails to provide `std::hash` if it's needed.
  It seems to be impossible to SFINAE on availability of `std::less` and `std::equal_to`, so I couldn't make similar assertions for those.
- In theory, you could support types that don't work with `std::less`, `std::equal_to` and/or `std::hash` by always considering all instances of one type equivalent, and using `typeid(T).hash_code()` as a hash.

  I'm not sure if that behavior is desirable or not, implementing it is left as an exercise to the reader.
  (Lack of SFINAE for `std::less` and `std::equal_to` will make it harder to implement properly.)
- Specifying custom replacements for `std::less`, `std::equal_to` and `std::hash` is not supported, implementing that is also left as an exercise to the reader.

  (This means that this implementation can only be used to put lambdas into a regular `std::set`, not `std::unordered_set`.)
- When applied to `FancyFunction`, `std::less` and `std::equal_to` will first compare types of stored functors.

  If types are identical, they'll resort to calling `std::less`/`std::equal_to` on underlying instances.

  (Thus, for two arbitrary different functor types, `std::less` will always consider instances of one of them less than instances of the other one. The order is not stable between program invocations.)

**Example usage:**

```
// With `std::set`:

#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct AddN
{
    int n;
    int operator()(int x) const {return n + x;}
    friend bool operator<(AddN a, AddN b) {return a.n < b.n;}
};

int main()
{   
    using func_t = FancyFunction<int(int), FunctionFlags::comparable_less>;

    // Note that `std::less` can operate on stateless lambdas by converting them to function pointers first. Otherwise this wouldn't work.
    auto square = [](int x){return x*x;};
    auto cube = [](int x){return x*x*x;};

    std::set<func_t> set;
    set.insert(square);
    set.insert(square); // Dupe.
    set.insert(cube);
    set.insert(AddN{100});
    set.insert(AddN{200});
    set.insert(AddN{200}); // Dupe.

    for (const auto &it : set)
        std::cout << "2 -> " << it(2) << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';
    /* Prints:
     * 2 -> 4   // `square`, note that it appears only once.
     * 2 -> 8   // `cube`
     * 2 -> 102 // `AddN{100}`
     * 2 -> 202 // `AddN{200}`, also appears once.
     */

    set.erase(set.find(cube));
    set.erase(set.find(AddN{100}));

    for (const auto &it : set)
        std::cout << "2 -> " << it(2) << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';
    /* Prints:
     * 2 -> 4   // `square`
     * 2 -> 202 // `AddN{200}`
     * `cube` and `AddN{100}` were removed.
     */
}


// With `std::unordered_set`:

#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

struct AddN
{
    int n;
    int operator()(int x) const {return n + x;}
    friend bool operator==(AddN a, AddN b) {return a.n == b.n;}
};

struct MulByN
{
    int n;
    int operator()(int x) const {return n * x;}
    friend bool operator==(MulByN a, MulByN b) {return a.n == b.n;}
};

namespace std
{
    template <> struct hash<AddN>
    {
        using argument_type = AddN;
        using result_type = std::size_t;
        size_t operator()(AddN f) const {return f.n;}
    };

    template <> struct hash<MulByN>
    {
        using argument_type = MulByN;
        using result_type = std::size_t;
        size_t operator()(MulByN f) const {return f.n;}
    };
}

int main()
{   
    using hashable_func_t = FancyFunction<int(int), FunctionFlags::hashable | FunctionFlags::comparable_eq>;
    std::unordered_set<hashable_func_t> set;
    set.insert(AddN{100});
    set.insert(AddN{100}); // Dupe.
    set.insert(AddN{200});
    set.insert(MulByN{10});
    set.insert(MulByN{20});
    set.insert(MulByN{20}); // Dupe.

    for (const auto &it : set)
        std::cout << "2 -> " << it(2) << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';
    /* Prints:
     * 2 -> 40  // `MulByN{20}`
     * 2 -> 20  // `MulByN{10}`
     * 2 -> 102 // `AddN{100}`
     * 2 -> 202 // `AddN{200}`
     */

    set.erase(set.find(AddN{100}));
    set.erase(set.find(MulByN{20}));

    for (const auto &it : set)
        std::cout << "2 -> " << it(2) << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';
    /* Prints:
     * 2 -> 20  // `MulByN{10}`
     * 2 -> 202 // `AddN{200}`
     * `MulByN{20}` and `AddN{100}` were removed.
     */
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <experimental/type_traits>
#include <utility>

enum class FunctionFlags
{
    none            = 0,
    comparable_less = 0b1,
    comparable_eq   = 0b10,
    hashable        = 0b100,
};
constexpr FunctionFlags operator|(FunctionFlags a, FunctionFlags b) {return FunctionFlags(int(a) | int(b));}
constexpr FunctionFlags operator&(FunctionFlags a, FunctionFlags b) {return FunctionFlags(int(a) & int(b));}


template <typename T> using detect_hashable = decltype(std::hash<T>{}(std::declval<const T &>()));


template <typename T, FunctionFlags Flags = FunctionFlags::none>
class FancyFunction;

template <typename ReturnType, typename ...ParamTypes, FunctionFlags Flags>
class FancyFunction<ReturnType(ParamTypes...), Flags>
{
    struct TypeDetails
    {
        int index = 0;
        bool (*less)(const void *, const void *) = 0;
        bool (*eq)(const void *, const void *) = 0;
        std::size_t (*hash)(const void *) = 0;

        inline static int index_counter = 0;
    };

    template <typename T> const TypeDetails *GetDetails()
    {
        static TypeDetails ret = []()
        {
            using type = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;

            TypeDetails d;

            d.index = TypeDetails::index_counter++;

            if constexpr (comparable_less)
            {
                // We can't SFINAE on `std::less`.
                d.less = [](const void *a_ptr, const void *b_ptr) -> bool
                {
                    const type &a = *static_cast<const FancyFunction *>(a_ptr)->func.template target<type>();
                    const type &b = *static_cast<const FancyFunction *>(b_ptr)->func.template target<type>();
                    return std::less<type>{}(a, b);
                };
            }

            if constexpr (comparable_eq)
            {
                // We can't SFINAE on `std::equal_to`.
                d.eq = [](const void *a_ptr, const void *b_ptr) -> bool
                {
                    const type &a = *static_cast<const FancyFunction *>(a_ptr)->func.template target<type>();
                    const type &b = *static_cast<const FancyFunction *>(b_ptr)->func.template target<type>();
                    return std::equal_to<type>{}(a, b);
                };
            }

            if constexpr (hashable)
            {
                static_assert(std::experimental::is_detected_v<detect_hashable, type>, "This type is not hashable.");
                d.hash = [](const void *a_ptr) -> std::size_t
                {
                    const type &a = *static_cast<const FancyFunction *>(a_ptr)->func.template target<type>();
                    return std::hash<type>(a);
                };
            }

            return d;
        }();
        return &ret;
    }

    std::function<ReturnType(ParamTypes...)> func;
    const TypeDetails *details = 0;

  public:
    inline static constexpr bool
        comparable_less = bool(Flags & FunctionFlags::comparable_less),
        comparable_eq   = bool(Flags & FunctionFlags::comparable_eq),
        hashable        = bool(Flags & FunctionFlags::hashable);

    FancyFunction(decltype(nullptr) = nullptr) {}

    template <typename T>
    FancyFunction(T &&obj)
    {
        func = std::forward<T>(obj);    
        details = GetDetails<T>();
    }

    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        return bool(func);
    }

    ReturnType operator()(ParamTypes ... params) const
    {
        return ReturnType(func(std::forward<ParamTypes>(params)...));
    }

    bool less(const FancyFunction &other) const
    {
        static_assert(comparable_less, "This function is disabled.");
        if (int delta = bool(details) - bool(other.details)) return delta < 0;
        if (!details) return 0;
        if (int delta = details->index - other.details->index) return delta < 0;
        return details->less(this, &other);
    }

    bool equal_to(const FancyFunction &other) const
    {
        static_assert(comparable_eq, "This function is disabled.");
        if (bool(details) != bool(other.details)) return 0;
        if (!details) return 1;
        if (details->index != other.details->index) return 0;
        return details->eq(this, &other);
    }

    std::size_t hash() const
    {
        static_assert(hashable, "This function is disabled.");
        if (!details) return 0;
        return details->hash(this);
    }

    friend bool operator<(const FancyFunction &a, const FancyFunction &b) {return a.less(b);}
    friend bool operator>(const FancyFunction &a, const FancyFunction &b) {return b.less(a);}
    friend bool operator<=(const FancyFunction &a, const FancyFunction &b) {return !b.less(a);}
    friend bool operator>=(const FancyFunction &a, const FancyFunction &b) {return !a.less(b);}
    friend bool operator==(const FancyFunction &a, const FancyFunction &b) {return a.equal_to(b);}
    friend bool operator!=(const FancyFunction &a, const FancyFunction &b) {return !a.equal_to(b);}
};

namespace std
{
    template <typename T, FunctionFlags Flags> struct hash<FancyFunction<T, Flags>>
    {
        using argument_type = FancyFunction<T, Flags>;
        using result_type = std::size_t;
        size_t operator()(const FancyFunction<T, Flags> &f) const
        {
            return f.hash();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer here. Thank you for taking the time! :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That was really nice.

Answer (score 8):

You can very well create an [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) of functions. The problem is that sets require an absolute order to exist between the values of its elements.  This order is defined by a comparator that is then used to sort the elements of a set, to check if an element already exists, and to find a specific element back.

Unfortunately, there doesn't exist an order between functions.  Suppose, that you have two functions `f1()` and `f2()`, what would be the meaning of `f1 < f2` ?

Also equality is not really defined. For example,  if you have

```
int fun1(int) { return 1; }
int fun2(int) { return 1; }
function<int(int)> f1=fun1, f2=fun2;
```

Should f1 and f2 be the same value if you'd insert them in a set (because it's always the same result), or is it something different (because it's different functions even though they have the same body) ?

Of course, you could trick the compiler in letting it believe that you have defined an order:

```
struct Comp {
    using T = function<int(int)>;
    bool operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const 
    {
        return &lhs < &rhs;
    }
};

set <function<int(int)>,Comp> s;
```

You could then insert functions in the set.  But this will not work very well, because you take the address of the element, and if the same elements are swapped, the order is different.

I think that the best way to proceed, would be to use a wrapper with a member string that defines an id and use this id to sort the elements in the set (or to do the hashing in case of an `unordered_set`)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can only check function-pointers for (in-)equality, not order. [And whether two functions with the same behavior must compare differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533740/do-distinct-functions-have-distinct-addresses/26534680#26534680) is not quite as cut-and-dry as you might perhaps hope for.

Next, you might not only store function-pointers, but also other callables. There is no guarantee any random user-defined class has a strict weak ordering. As an example, lambdas don't.

And finally, how would you order callables of different types?

You can make the same Argument for hashing (needed for unordered containers) as for ordering (needed for ordered containers). Even the equality-comparison needed for unordered containers might not exist.

Answer (score 1):

There is no meaningful equality operation for the general function, held by a `std::function`.

- C++ functions aren't mathematical functions.  What if the "function" holds state?  And that state is different for different instances?
- To your suggestion of using the "entry point address": Again, consider state.  A `std::function` can hold a bind of some function/method to some parameters. What is the "entry point address" of that?  Ans: Some function/method in the "bind" package.  And does then that "entry point address" uniquely identify that function? Ans: No.
- Suppose you have two different functions (by "entry point address") that in fact are identical in the sense that they produce the same result for every parameter?  They may even be the same source code - or machine code.  Are those functions equal, or not?  (If not, why not, if they're behaviorally identical and can't be distinguished by any caller?)

Your particular use case (for sticking `std::function` in a set) may not be impacted by the above issues.  In that case simply wrap the `std::function` instance in a small struct of your own (either via direct containment or via indirection) (forwarding calls to the contained function object) and put those things in your set.