# C++ std::list with std::function: calling remove() won't build

Tags: c++, stl

can someone explain me why this code won't build:

```cpp
std::function<void(int)> intcb = [](int a)
{
    std::cout << "callback: " << a << std::endl;
};

std::list<std::function<void(int)>> list;
list.push_back(intcb);
list.remove(intcb);
```

build error located in remove function:

```
no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::function<void(int)>' and 'const value_type' {aka 'const std::function<void(int)>'})
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Should the solution work for lambdas with a capture? If you don't need functions with state, you can use plain function pointers.

Comment: as a simpler, but more expensive, alternative you can consider to store the functions in a `std::unordered_map<tag_t,std::function<void(int)>` so you can remove them based on some tag.

Comment: `std::function`s can't be compared with each other using `==`. But you can make your own wrapper for it that is comparable. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53462084/2752075

Comment: for the moment i think the `std::unordered_map` idea is the best solution ... i will try it that way :-) thanks to all for your help

Comment: Do you need to execute the callbacks in a certain order? Otherwise you could just use `pop_back()` or `pop_front()`

Answer (score 5):

Well, you want to create a list of functions and then enable "remove" functionality, but for removal operation list needs to be able to compare instances of its type, because it does not rely on references to objects.

So you need to somehow define `operator==` for your specified function type

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. What is the best way to implement such operator for a templated `std::function`?

Comment: You could use 
`std::list<std::function<void(int)>*> list; list.push_back(&intcb); list.remove(&intcb);` although that's a bit hacky....

Comment: Thanks @Den-Jason. This solution looks a little bit "old-school" to me :-D but if there is no better solution, i will make it that way.

Comment: @Kill_Switch just be careful with the pointers, because you then need to make sure that the original `intcb` is alive from insertion till removal, ie the quesiton arises: Why put it inside the list in the first place, when anyhow you need to keep the original alive seperate from the list

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 your completely right, using the old-school pointer stuff might be dangerous. when is call push_back() i will only have a reference to a temporary std::function object living on the caller stack...

Answer (score 0):

Does this make sense: what you have in your list is function object and while you put it to the list you're actually copying the intcb. So you need a way to compare the copies. Instead you can try storing by pointer, so removing will work by comparing addresses which works out of the box.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <functional>

std::function<void(int)> intcb = [](int a)
{
    std::cout << "callback: " << a << std::endl;
};


int main() {
    std::list<std::function<void(int)>*> list;
    list.push_back(&intcb);
    list.remove(&intcb);
    return 0;
}
```