# Can a compiler elide the bodies of functions that are address-taken but never called?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, compiler-optimization, stdany, comdat-folding

[Background information](/q/51361606)

---

Consider this simplified implementation of `std::any` (irrelevant parts omitted) and some code that uses it:

```
namespace std {
  namespace details {
    // Each instance of this function template has a different address
    template <typename T>
    const char *dummy_function() { return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; }

    template <typename T> void *construct(T &&);
    void destroy(void *storage, const char *(*type_identifier)());
  }

  class any {
    const char *(*type_identifier)();
    void *storage;

  public:
    template <typename Arg>
    any(Arg &&arg)
      : type_identifier(&details::dummy_function<decay_t<Arg>>)
      , storage(details::construct(forward<Arg>(arg))) {}

    template <typename Arg>
    any &operator=(Arg &&arg) {
      details::destroy(storage, type_identifier);
      type_identifier = &details::dummy_function<decay_t<Arg>>;
      storage = details::construct(forward<Arg>(arg));
    }

    template <typename T>
    friend T *any_cast(any *source) {
      if (source && source->type_identifier == &dummy_function<T>)
        return static_cast<T *>(source->storage);
      return nullptr;
    }
  };
}
```

```
#include <any>

// Code that compares any::type_identifier a lot but never calls through it
std::any any = 42;
assert(std::any_cast<int>(&any) != nullptr);
assert(std::any_cast<double>(&any) == nullptr);

any = std::string("Hello");
assert(std::any_cast<std::string>(&any) != nullptr);
assert(std::any_cast<std::vector<char>>(&any) == nullptr);
```

If an optimizing compiler can prove that `std::details::dummy_function<T>` is never called in any manner throughout the program, is the compiler permitted to not include the function body of `std::details::dummy_function<T>` (along with the thereby unreferenced `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`s) for any `T` in the compilation result (and even possibly make their addresses arbitrary pointer-sized integers that are just guaranteed to be distinct but otherwise may not even be valid memory addresses)?

(Or could even the addresses not guaranteed to be distinct for distinct `T`s, which unfortunately means my implementation is incorrect to begin with?)

Comment: Is it allowed to: Yes. Can it: In theory, if the compiler can prove that the function pointer is never called. In practice: Probably not, because the mentioned proof is difficult in general.

Comment: Related: [What exactly is the “as-if” rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15718262/978917)

Comment: Also related: [Do distinct functions have distinct addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26533740/978917)

Comment: The compller can't even determine that it's never called, given that someone has its address.